# Testing in ASP.net MVC Beta 1

Tags: unit-testing, controller, asp.net-mvc-beta1

I'm wring a unit test for a controller and here is my code.

```
public void DocumentController_IndexMethod_ShouldReturn_Documents()
    {
        DocumentsController c = new DocumentsController(_repository);

        ViewResult result = (ViewResult)c.Index("1");

        DocumentsController.DocumentsData data = (DocumentsController.DocumentsData)result.ViewData;

        Assert.IsNotNull(data.Documents);
        Assert.IsTrue(data.Documents.Count() > 0);

        Assert.IsNotNull(result);
    }
```

I'm basically following along with Rob Conery's asp.net storefront application and realized that I can't use the RenderView method.  As shown I have tried the ViewResult method to create an instance of the view.  I'm getting this error:
Error   1   Cannot convert type 'System.Web.Mvc.ViewDataDictionary' to 'HomeOwners.Controllers.DocumentsController.DocumentsData'   C:\Documents and Settings\drmarshall\My Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\HomeOwners\HomeOwners.Tests\DocumentsControllerTests.cs   61  54  HomeOwners.Tests

Am I using the correct replacement method or am I missing something?

I figured it out.

```
[TestMethod]
    public void DocumentController_IndexMethod_ShouldReturn_Documents()
    {
        DocumentsController c = new DocumentsController(_repository);

        ViewResult result = c.Index("1") as ViewResult;

        ViewDataDictionary dictionary = result.ViewData;

        DocumentsController.DocumentsData data = (DocumentsController.DocumentsData)dictionary["Documents"];

        Assert.IsNotNull(data.Documents);
        Assert.IsTrue(data.Documents.Count() > 0);

        Assert.IsNotNull(result);
    }
```

Comment: If there is a question here, I cannot tell what it is.

Comment: Have you resolved your problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[TestMethod]
    public void DocumentController_IndexMethod_ShouldReturn_Documents()
    {
        DocumentsController c = new DocumentsController(_repository);

```
    ViewResult result = c.Index("1") as ViewResult;

    ViewDataDictionary dictionary = result.ViewData;

    DocumentsController.DocumentsData data = (DocumentsController.DocumentsData)dictionary["Documents"];

    Assert.IsNotNull(data.Documents);
    Assert.IsTrue(data.Documents.Count() > 0);

    Assert.IsNotNull(result);
}
```